# How to move shared albums data from Photos externally

Tags: photos, photos.app, symlink

I recently moved my Photos library to an external SSD. Unfortunately shared album data still lives locally inside `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.cloudphotosd/Data/Library/Application Support/com.apple.cloudphotosd/services/com.apple.photo.icloud.sharedstreams/`

I tried symlinking the folder to the external SSD, but Photos seems to overwrite the symlink.

Is there a known workaround to moved shared album data externally?